# Connect Lenovo Thinkpad Edge e120 to WQHD display (such as Dell U2711) through HDMI

Tags: display, hdmi, thinkpad

On paper, the HDMI version of the Lenovo Thinkpad Edge e120 is 1.3, which supports WQHD.

Does it actually work?

I want to connect the e120 to a WQHD display, such as the Dell U2711 or an Apple Cinema Display. I run Windows 7 Ultimate and latest drivers. The e120 I think has the Intel HD Graphics 3000 onboard chipset.

I don't have the chance to test out the e120 with neither of these displays, so I'm seeking for an opinion from those who have tried.